# How to integrate sass with compilation into css using webpack.config in angular 4 and above version?

Tags: css, angular, sass

How to integrate sass with compilation into css using webpack.config.js in angular 4 and above version ?

Comment: Is this AngularCli generated project ?

Comment: Yes it is AngularCLI generated !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular v4, v5 go to your `.angular.cli.json` and change the property `"styles":["styles.css"]` to `"styles":["styles.scss"]` and the property `"styleExt":css` to `styleExt:"scss"` , for version 6 go to `angular.json` and do the same thing * in angular 6 the `styleExt` is `styleext` the styleext is used to autogenerate `.scss` files in your new components instead of `.css` when generating new ones with the cli + rename all your files and file paths from `.css` to `.scss`

Comment: thank you so much for you help, sir, I am expecting to compile scss into css

Answer (score 0):

for using sass,you have to make changes in the angular-cli.json , for that use the command

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

what it will do is make changes in the angular-cli.json  file and add changes like this

```
 "defaults": {
 "styleExt": "scss",
 "component": {
 } 
}
```

after running the command, make sure you change the **styles** array to **styles.sass** 
and create main styles file in your src directory similar to styles.css now it will be styles.sass and **import** the styles file of all component's into the main styles file.